# Heroku dyno keeps rebooting constantly

Tags: node.js, heroku, dyno

I've just deployed a new project to Heroku using Docker.

Unfortunately, my dyno is in a reboot cycle and hasn't come online yet. It continuously crashes with the following logs:

```
2021-01-07T09:49:55.706527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-01-07T09:51:44.917593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c NODE_ENV\=production\ node\ ./dist/apps/server/main.js`
2021-01-07T09:51:45.800006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2021-01-07T09:51:45.802340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-01-07T09:51:54.256090+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on :39134
2021-01-07T09:51:55.807447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-07T09:51:56.049759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-01-07T09:52:09.979061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-01-07T09:53:18.197373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=a031ff96-2a06-46e0-85da-458f83430f0d fwd="49.178.36.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-07T09:53:33.346139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c NODE_ENV\=production\ node\ ./dist/apps/server/main.js`
2021-01-07T09:53:39.162417+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on :45111
2021-01-07T09:53:40.774891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-01-07T09:53:40.887655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

I've tried upgrading the dyno to `Hobby`, rebooted all dynos multiple times but nothing seems to fix it.

I am indeed listening on `process.env.PORT`.

Comment: Nothing here suggests that you need to upgrade your dynos. Do you have a `Procfile`? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: I don't have a Procfile - It recently started working randomly but I had this issue for a couple of hours.

Comment: What does "It recently started working randomly but I had this issue for a couple of hours" mean? It's working now? Sporadically? It was working but now it's not? Please read [ask].

Comment: "It recently started working randomly but I had this issue for a couple of hours" means "It recently started working randomly but I had this issue for a couple of hours". Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The issue still occurs quite frequently

Comment: Thank you, I already know how to answer. That's why I asked for clarification in a _comment_.