# How to stop using up free dynos on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, paas, dyno

Most answers I've found here are a couple years old and thus the services on Heroku.com barely match with the answers here as things keep changing and it's driving me nuts.

I looked up and researched but all of them don't seem to work and looks like I'm not the only one having this issue.
[How to stop an app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811453/how-to-stop-an-app-on-heroku) 
[How to stop a heroku server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156498/how-to-stop-a-heroku-server) 
[Heroku dyno keeps rebooting constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610113/heroku-dyno-keeps-rebooting-constantly)

I did turn on maintenance mode with `heroku maintenance:on` and web to 0 with `heroku ps:scale web=0` as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode) but my app still keeps using up my free dynos.
My app's resources are also off (I use to run the node worker) 
My Procfile: `Worker: node myapp.js`

Despite all settings made above my used up dynos still keep increasing daily even though it says `No dynos on myapp`. I always check it via CLI:

```
$ heroku ps -a myapp
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 36h 13m (6%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 513h 46m (93%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

No dynos on ⬢ myapp
```

I am also aware that dynos automatically restart when following things happen as written [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts):

```
- create a new release by deploying new code
- change your config vars
- change your add-ons
- run heroku restart
```

But none of these apply as I never changed my code or vars from the day I've been trying to "stop" the app.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I would try to scale down the worker `heroku ps:scale worker=0`

Comment: Oh I posted a response but I didn't see that the app's Resources were already off, I deleted it

Comment: Somehow, it is fixed. It's no more counting the dynos. It probably was an issue on their end or not sure. I might as well be deletíng this question or provide my settings as an answer in case people find a similar problem. Thanks for the little responses though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, it's been fixed for some reason after a while but I didn't do anything different than before except that I've changed maintenance mode through the website - not via CLI. I performed the following changes.

- Turn on maintenance mode through website
- Entered this in the CLI: `heroku ps:scale web=0 -a myapp`
- Resources are all offline

I provided these settings in case people got similar issues.